# How to set up data value from database to rb-tab and add rb-tab-active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

Good Night from Malang.
I have a question about how to setting up some rb-tab with a data from database that I want to store the data in to rb-tab.

First, this is the view "rb-tab"

```
                    <div class="rb" id="rb-1">
                      <div class="rb-tab" name="f21" data-value="1">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Sangat Besar</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" name="f21" data-value="2">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Besar</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" name="f21" data-value="3">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Cukup Besar</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" name="f21" data-value="4">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Kurang</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="rb-tab" name="f21" data-value="5">
                        <div class="rb-spot">
                          <span class="rb-txt">Tidak Sama Sekali</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

And then, this is The Controllers

```
 // ambil data tracer study per id alumni
    $dataTs['row'] = $this->mTracerStudyAlumni->ambil_data_ts_per_id($id_alumni);
    // jika belum mengisi ts, set data 0 untuk tampilan default 
    if($dataTs['row']==null)
    {
      $data['f21'] = 0;
    }
    // jika sudah ada data ts yang disimpan 
    else
    {
      $data['f21'] = $dataTs['row']->f21;
    }
```

We want value on $data['f21'] can be store to the view, and add class rb-tab active on that view.

I hope for your any suggestion, advice, and information for this situasion.
Thank you very much, for all your any help for this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
 $(function(){
      $(".rb-tab").find('[data-value=<?= $f21 ?>').addClass( "active" );
    })
```

Comment: Thanks @rizky rahardian , I'm still confused about this. I've appreciate, if you give us more, how to write down this code correctly like what do you mean.

Comment: by using your code it is only need sent variable $f21 and sent to view and it will find the data-value with value from $f21 from class rb-tab and adding class active

Comment: Thanks @rizky raharidan, I've tried your solution, but In the view It's still can't adding "active" class on rb-tab. This is the code what I've tried.

Comment: //javascript
      // fungsi pemindah
      $(".rb-tab").click(function(){
        // pemindah spot
        $(this).parent().find(".rb-tab").removeClass("rb-tab-active");
        $(this).addClass("rb-tab-active");
      });